# How to get Data from a Firebase Database and populate them in a ListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

```
{
  "chat_room" : {
    "-Kp_ldAz7_g3W4riNkJY" : {
      "message" : "Hello!",
      "uname" : "Praveen"
    }
  }
}
```

this is my Firebase DB jSON file for a single chat message, i tried the following method i created called "appendChat()" to populate the database on a ListView.

but for some reason the ListView only shows the last message sent

```
    private void appendChat(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            final ArrayList<String> chatListArr = new ArrayList<String>();
            Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                chatListArr.add((String) ((DataSnapshot) i.next()).getValue());
                chatListArr.add((String) ((DataSnapshot) i.next()).getValue());

           }
            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,android.R.id.text1, chatListArr);
            chatList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

My ListView has a String for the username and a sub string for the message, how do i change the code to retrieve database values and populate in a ListView as

```
username:
   message
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a brand new `ArrayAdapter` each time a message is received. This effectively deletes all of the previous messages. I suggest that you create the `ArrayAdapter` once in `onCreate()`. Then you can just add data to the `ArrayList` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.